# Responsive Grid With Padding Image Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

I have the following grid system in place:

http://jsfiddle.net/tev60L6z/1

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.third {
  float: left;
  width: 33.334%;
  padding-right: 24px;
}
.last {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <article class="third">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6Q23mHrTwxc/UxGT360FBMI/AAAAAAAAAJ0/pj86RO2vGyg/s320/google-maps-api.jpg" alt="image" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
  </article>
  <article class="third">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6Q23mHrTwxc/UxGT360FBMI/AAAAAAAAAJ0/pj86RO2vGyg/s320/google-maps-api.jpg" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
  </article>
  <article class="third last">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6Q23mHrTwxc/UxGT360FBMI/AAAAAAAAAJ0/pj86RO2vGyg/s320/google-maps-api.jpg" alt="image" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

The 3 columns sit equally within my container, but the height of the last image is greater than the rest. I understand this is happening because the third column doesn't have padding.

Is there a solution to equalise the image heights whilst maintaining 3 equal widths? I've tried `max-width` on the image, but this adds a 24px gap to the right of the third column.

Comment: It would be much easier to anwser if you managed to reproduce your issue in a fiddle or other.

Comment: Thank you, I have provided a link in my edited question :)

Comment: because your image is set to 100% of the area, and you added no padding, it will grab the fill width of your `.last` container, thus which is indeed, bigger than the others. Consider it giving a padding as well or at least a `padding-left` or `padding-right` to line out what you want

Comment: Edit: I overread, and saw you added that already. And because you remove the padding-right from your item, it wont go well.. consider doing something then like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tev60L6z/3/

Comment: Leave the padding on the last column and give the container a -24px right margin.

Comment: I like the negative margin on the container solution as this will allow me to keep my px based padding. Only problem is, my container is set to `margin: 0 auto`...

Comment: Ok then you can keep that container with it's margins and give it `overflow:hidden;` and put an other container inside with the negative margin.

Comment: You legend! Works a treat. Please add it as your answer and I'll mark as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to leave the padding on the last item and use negative right margin on a container :

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap {
  margin-right: -24px;
}
.third {
  float: left;
  width: 33.334%;
  padding-right: 24px;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="wrap">
    <article class="third">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6Q23mHrTwxc/UxGT360FBMI/AAAAAAAAAJ0/pj86RO2vGyg/s320/google-maps-api.jpg" alt="image" />
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <p>Description</p>
    </article>
    <article class="third">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6Q23mHrTwxc/UxGT360FBMI/AAAAAAAAAJ0/pj86RO2vGyg/s320/google-maps-api.jpg" />
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <p>Description</p>
    </article>
    <article class="third last">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6Q23mHrTwxc/UxGT360FBMI/AAAAAAAAAJ0/pj86RO2vGyg/s320/google-maps-api.jpg" alt="image" />
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <p>Description</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

reference : [grid with inner padding only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328858/items-grid-with-inner-padding-only/23875329#23875329)