# 3 Fluid Divs width 2 Fixed Margins between them?

Tags: css, margin, grid-layout, fluid-layout, fixed-width

I have the following setup, but setting the width of the divs to a something around 30% is not working consistently (once the window width goes  less than some number the third divs drops below..

Is there a better way of doing this, so that my divs always stay inline and keep getting smaller and smaller while the margin stays fixed at 18px between them ?

**CSS :**

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}  

.child {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 18px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: ~30%; /* doesn't work */
}  

.child:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for IE8 support, and can change your markup, you can nest the blocks inside 33.33% width elements.

For IE8 support, you need to [get rid of the `nth-child()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) declaration. In order to have inner gaps only, I used the technique described here : [Items grid with inner padding only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328858/items-grid-with-inner-padding-only/23875329#23875329).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hrda3568/)**

```css
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
}
.wrap{
    margin: 0 -9px;
}
.box {
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
}
.box div {
    background:grey;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <div>one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` to calculate column width.

```
.child {width: calc(33.333% - 12px);} /* margins in total have 36px / 3 cols  */
```

`Calc` is supported since IE9.

Comment: Any solutions for IE8+ ?

Comment: @SproutCoder: no, there is the only solution to use percentage margins (eg. using cond. comment for IE8). In your main stylesheet you can have `calc` and under that link a stylesheet for IE8 only with overwritten `margin` and `width` for `.child`.