# Create a 4x4 responsive grid of squares with a margin of 20px on each side of the container?

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I want to create a grid of *responsive* 4x4 squares with a margin of exactly 20px on the left and right sides of the overall container. Furthermore, this would effectively eliminate the *left margin* on the first squares in each row and also eliminate the *right margin* on the last squares in each row since double margins aren't needed.

> *The green color notes the 20px margins on each side.*

[image]

I've so far created the grid of squares with percentages but the problem is that, since I am applying a margin to all sides of each square, this method does not guarantee a left and right margin (on the container) of 20px each.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p9qdhfub/1/

HTML

```
<section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    height: 24vw;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 23%;
}
```

### Question

How would I be able to create a 4x4 responsive grid of squares with the container (i.e. `section`) always having a `margin-left` of 20px and a `margin-right` of 20px?

Comment: I've never used it, but I'm sure plenty of people are going to say it: use `flexbox`.

Comment: Wait a second, `px` or `%`?

Comment: Why don't you set 20px margin to the `<section>` element?

Comment: @Roko Because then the first square in each row will have an added left margin and the last square in each row will have an added right margin.

Comment: @J82 so you need always a 20px outer margin, but keep inner margins at %. If yes see my example.

Comment: related : [Items grid with inner padding only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328858/items-grid-with-inner-padding-only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add

```
section{
    margin:-1%;
    padding:20px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/p9qdhfub/9/)**

This way you can have your 20px fixed gutters on each side of the container. To remove the horizontal scrollbar, you can add an other container with `overflow:hidden;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/p9qdhfub/10/)**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.w {
  overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  margin: -1%;
  padding: 20px;
}
section div {
  background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 24vw;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 23%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

***[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9qdhfub/8/)***

Section will always have 20px margin;
Every first(+4) DIV will have a left margin of 0;
Every fourth DIV will have a right margin of 0;

```
div {
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    height: 24vw;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 23.5%;
}
div:nth-child(4n-3){
    background:red;
    margin-left:0; /* or use 20px */
}
div:nth-child(4n){
    background:blue;
    margin-right:0; /* or use 20px */
}
section{
    margin:0 20px; /* so you don't need this any more */
}
```

Comment: This one nails it in my opinion - the only thing I'd add that instead of putting `height:24vw` you can get a nice 'square' appearance by doing an after element with `content:'';display:block;position:relative;padding-bottom:100%;` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/p9qdhfub/11/