# Remove right margin on last inline element

Tags: html, css

I have a footer `div` with inner `span` buttons.

Each button have `margin-right: 20px` and the `.footer` element has `padding: 0 13px`.

I want to **prevent the `margin-right` of the most right button** by setting negative `margin-right` to its parent.

How could I get it with `margin-right`?

```css
.footer {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 0 13px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <span class="btn">Btn1</span>
  <span class="btn">Btn2</span>
</div>
```

I am **not** looking for a solution with the [last child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) *CSS* pseudo-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another container child of `.footer` and apply a negative `margin-right` to that element. This approach is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875329/1811992):

```css
.footer {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 0 13px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.footer > div {
  margin-right:-33px;
  }

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div>
    <span class="btn">Btn1</span>
    <span class="btn">Btn2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note you also need to a d `overflow:hidden;` to the `.footer` element to prevent horizontal scrollbar.*